# 2点間の距離を求めるプログラム

Tags: c

２点間の距離を求めたいので、以下のようにプログラムしました。
（実行例も貼り付けておきます。）

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define sqr(n) ((n)*(n))

struct point{
    double X;
    double Y;
};

struct point input_point(void)
{
    struct point t;

    printf("X座標: ");
    scanf("%lf", &t.X);
    printf("Y座標: ");
    scanf("%lf", &t.Y);

    return t;
}

void  print_point(struct point t)
{
    printf("(%0.2f)\n",t.X+t.Y);
}

struct point add_point(struct point a,struct point b)
{
    struct point t;
    t.X+t.Y=sqrt(sqr(a.X-b.X)+sqr(a.Y-b.Y));
    return t;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct point a, b, m;

    printf("座標 A\n");
    a = input_point();
    printf("座標 B\n");
    b = input_point();

    m=add_point(a,b);

    printf("座標 AB間の距離: ");
    print_point(m);

    return 0;
}
```

```
実行例：
$ ./a.out
Aの座標を入力:
X座標: 1
Y座標: 1
Bの座標を入力:
X座標: 0
Y座標: 0
線分ABの長さ: 1.41
```

ですが、エラーが以下のように出てきてしまいました。

```
$ cc ex1104.c -lm
ex1104.c: In function ‘add_point’:
ex1104.c:36:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     t.X+t.Y=sqrt(sqr(a.X-b.X)+sqr(a.Y-b.Y));
            ^
```

このエラーから、add_point の部分がおかしいことはわかったのですが、どこがおかしいのかがわかりません。

Comment: 2点間の距離を求めたいとのことですが、ソースコードでは(「点」を返す)`add_point`を用いているように見受けました。どちらを求めたいのでしょうか?

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。自分は２点間の距離を求めるためのソースコードを入力したつもりでした。自分のプログラムミスだと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーそのものは、`t.X+t.Y`という足し算の結果に`sqrt(sqr(a.X-b.X)+sqr(a.Y-b.Y))`という値を代入しようとしているので、そんなことはできないと言っています。

しかし、そもそもの原因は、2点間の距離はスカラー値、つまり実数が一つの値なのに、座標値として返そうとしていることにあります。距離の型は`double`であるべきです。

関数`add_point()`は

```
double add_point(struct point a,struct point b)
{
    return sqrt(sqr(a.X-b.X)+sqr(a.Y-b.Y));
}
```

とし、`main()`は

```
int main(void)
{
    struct point a, b;
    double m;

    printf("座標 A\n");
    a = input_point();
    printf("座標 B\n");
    b = input_point();

    m=add_point(a,b);

    printf("座標 AB間の距離: %f\n", m);

    return 0;
}
```

とすれば、距離が求められます。

Comment: お返事遅れてすみません。回答ありがとうございます。きちんとコンパイルできました。